# WordPress 3.6.1 + Turbolink + Pace.js help needed

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've tried to install Pace.js script on my own blog — http://www.thewired.ru and I have some feeling that I've failed a bit. Can someone of you please tell me what's going wrong with it?

Problem is that sometimes it does not work and sometimes it works not smoothly. What's wrong?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It seems to work every time for me, were you able to fix it?

Comment: For my regret — not yet. Try to navigate from one blog post to another and u will see that sometimes pace.js fails :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `restartOnPushState` disabled, which is why it's not restarting when you navigate between posts.

`<script data-pace-options='{ "restartOnPushState": false, "restartOnRequestAfter": false }' src="http://www.thewired.ru/js/pace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`